# How to create custom POST operation with embedded collection relation?

Tags: php, api-platform.com

I am trying to create a custom POST operation that contains a collection of embedded relations.

I would like the body of the request to be as follows:

```
POST /greeting
{
    "name": "string",
    "comments": [
         {
             "name": "string",
             "number": 123123
         },
         {
             "name": "string",
             "number": 123123
         }
    ]
}
```

Then, I'd like the request to be mapped to a `Greeting` object that contains the name and an array of `Comment` objects.

This is what I've done:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiSubresource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * This is a dummy entity. Remove it!
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"write"}}
 * )
 */
class Greeting
{
    /**
     * @var string A nice person
     * @Groups({"write"})
     */
    public $name = '';

    /**
     * @var Comment
     * @Groups({"write"})
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
    public $comment;
}
```

And this is the comment entity:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * This is a dummy entity. Remove it!
 *
 * @ApiResource(
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"write"}}
 * )
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Groups({"write"})
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @Groups({"write"})
     */
    public $number;
}
```

The problem is that the comment is interpreted as "string" in the API documentation. **I know that I am directly referencing the Comment instead of an array of comments, but I just wanted to get a simple one-to-one relation working first**.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: You did not add a doctrine mapping relation between Greeting#comment and Comment.

Comment: @Mario2002 I was not aware that is a requirement. I cannot use doctrine here, I want to handle the persistence in a custom way. Is it now working without doctrine mappings?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution on github: https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1227

It was a bug in the Swagger UI generator, the request was denormalized fine. In v2.4.6 the Swagger UI was also fixed. The code I posted above works fine and it doesn't require Doctrine.